# Error in cv.glmnet for poisson with an offset

Tags: r, cross-validation, poisson, glmnet, offset

I am facing an error when trying to run a cross validation on glmnet for family = poisson using an **offset**.

I managed to replicate the error with the very simple example below:

```
library(glmnet)

#poisson
N=500; p=20
nzc=5
x=matrix(rnorm(N*p),N,p)
beta=rnorm(nzc)
f = x[,seq(nzc)]%*%beta
mu=exp(f)
y=rpois(N,mu)
exposure=rep(0.5,length(y))

#cross validation
cv=cv.glmnet(x,y,family="poisson",offset=log(exposure),nlambda=50,nfolds=3)
```

which returns the following error:

> Error: No newoffset provided for prediction, yet offset used in fit of
>   glmnet

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. And wasn't able to find any help on the internet. Would anyone have ideas?

Thanks a lot!

> **EDIT** : this issue is obsolete, and was linked to the version `2.0-12` of the `glmnet` package - fixed when updating to version `2.0-13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:
`predict(cv,x,newoffset=log(exposure))`

From the documentation for `glmnet` for the `offset` parameter:

> If supplied, then values must also be supplied to the predict
>   function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my error is actually on the modelling, not on the predict. Can I just ask you which version of the glmnet package you are using? I have a feeling that it might be because of my version (2.0-12).

Comment: The code you posted runs for me without error, on `glmnet_2.0-13`

Comment: The error you posted only shows up for `predict`, however, not the model fit - are you sure you aren't trying to run `predict` after the lines of code you posted?

Comment: OK, I'll update and let you know. Thanks a lot! This has been annoying me for the past days, and I would never had thought it might be linked a package version.

Comment: Yes, it showed up in the model fit, as crazy as it seems. But as it is doing a cross validation, it is predicting also during the model fit.

Comment: Ok, updated the package to version 2.0-13, and everything is running fine now. The version 2.0-12 was only on CRAN for a few days, so I guessed they realised there were some bugs! Thanks a lot.